# Fix Google PageSpeed's "Serve scaled images" for responsive layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, pagespeed

My layout is responsive so I need to have scaled images put into the template, e.g. when using mobile devices, the `span3` of `Boostrap` might occupy  a full row so the width will be increased.

But in the Google PageSpeed it is marked as an issue.

Are there any workaround or a better way to handle this?

Comment: Currently at 98/100 on a responsive website and I'm facing the same issue as you with images. Frustrating as I'd love to get it to 100!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled compression gzip or deflate mode? It tells us because either we didn't use cache (either browser or proxy). Write this in your header/ .htaccess file.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|svg|pdf|flv|mp3)$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive on
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month 2 days 3 hours" //example you can change it
 Header set Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

And one thing if browser still ignores it. You can also use [Adaptive-Images](http://adaptive-images.com) method to sever your assets as per less DNS look-ups and scaled down for small-devices.

If you use one of those methods, you don't have to worry about images-scaled or not. 
I have tried all [these things](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload#ScaleImages) and got **98** out **100** Page Speed.

You can believe if you check out the page speed of this [page](http://scaledrop.com). Hope you better fix it too.

Comment: Akshaya, it's a bit disingenuous to refer to the page